# Specialization of operators inside template class between objects of different specialization of that class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have the following problem/question:
Suppose that i have a template class Couple which have two attributes x and y of type xobject.
I can easily define the sum between Couple of the same class simply defining the sum element by element, if it is defined the sum of the template object, i.e.:

```
Couple operator+(Couple in)
{
 return Couple((*this).x+in.x,(*this).y+in.y);
}
```

With this implementation i can compute the sum between `Couple<int>` element.
I don't exactly understand how i can define the sum between `Couple<int>` and `Couple<something>` inside that class.
The problem is that i cannot specialize the sum inside the class between classes that are not yet implemented, i.e., i cannot write

```
Couple<'int'> Couple<'int'>::operator+(Couple<'something'>)
```

inside the Couple class.
Do you have any idea how to do this?
My first idea was to use a second template parameter inside the operator but the results was not so good since doing this i allow only the one verse sum and not in both verse.
I hope that i explained the problem in a decent way.

Comment: Do you really need specializations?  Normally you would use something like `template <typename T> struct foo { template<typename U> foo<T> operator+(foo<U> rhs) { stuff } };`

Comment: If you want to apply type conversions on all parameters ( including the one pointed to by `this` ) to a function the function has to be at least a non-member function (may even a friend function ).

Comment: The double template should not work since the sum of Couple<int> and Couple<double> is different from the sum Couple<double> and Couple<int> (it differs for the output, and i don't want to use C++14).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `friend` template function:

```
template <typename T>
class Couple
{
private:
    T x, y;

public:
    Couple(T xx, T xy) : x{xx}, y{xy} { }

    template <typename T0, typename T1>
    friend Couple<std::common_type_t<T0, T1>> 
    operator+(const Couple<T0>& x0, const Couple<T1>& x1);
};

template <typename T0, typename T1>
Couple<std::common_type_t<T0, T1>> 
operator+(const Couple<T0>& x0, const Couple<T1>& x1)
{
    return {x0.x + x1.x, x0.y + x1.y};
}
```

I am using `std::common_type_t` to compute a type that suitable for the `T0 + T1` addition.

[**coliru example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a72b4efd586f4987)

---

You may not need `friend` if you expose getters for `x` and `y`, as **SebTu** mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Consider that a friend function is only necessary if it requires access to the private data members. Otherwise a non-member non-friend function is enough. `y` and `x` should may be encapsulated in `getter()` functions.

Comment: I don't want to use C++14

Comment: @Nicola: why not? The code is easily adaptable to C++11. Regardless, you should have mentioned that in the question

Comment: How can i adapt it?